# How to retrieve data from google drive hidden app folder?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am creating a app in which I store the user information in the user drive hidden app folder. However when I try to retrieve that information it's gives an Exception. Below is my sample code and If you have any other solution so, please provide me. Thanks in Advance

```
private void getDataFromDrive(){
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(syncCallBack);

    }


private ResultCallback<Status> syncCallBack = new ResultCallback<Status>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                    if (DriveStatusCodes.DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED == status.getStatusCode()) {
                        //intimate user to wait for some time if you want to
                    }
                }
                //now query db file from google drive's app folder
                queryMethod();
            }
        };

    private void queryMethod() {

        Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "New file.txt"))
                .build();
        Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = getDriveResourceClient().query(query);

        queryTask.addOnSuccessListener(this,
                new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "retrieving files");
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.query_pass));
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "---->Enter In Open File Fail");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving files");
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.query_failed));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzba.zze(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls.requestSync(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudbackupdemo.BaseDemoActivity.getDataFromDrive(BaseDemoActivity.java:179)
        at com.cloudbackupdemo.BaseDemoActivity.onClick(BaseDemoActivity.java:161)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: `getDataFromDrive` where do you call this method?

Comment: on a button click i call this method.

Comment: ok,but the button where is called?